# Why my file is not saved? XmlSerializer in WinRT

Tags: xml-serialization, windows-runtime, storage

I'm working with a XmlSerializer, every time a item gets added to my list I call the save method:

```
async public void save(List<string> eingabe)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));

    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile sampleFile = 
        await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(speicherPfad, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var file = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

    serializer.Serialize(file.AsStreamForWrite(), eingabe);

    file.Dispose();
}
```

when the app starts I call the load method:

```
public async Task<List<string>> load()
{
    List<string> ausgabe = new List<string>();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));

    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(speicherPfad, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    var file = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    List<string> speicher = (List<string>)serializer.Deserialize(file.AsStreamForRead());

    file.Dispose();

    return speicher;
}
```

the problem: **in the load method, file is always empty (Size = 0) and i dont know why**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of this option: `CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting`.

As a side note, it would be a good idea to change `save` to return `Task` and `await` it.